# preg_match only show replacement if found

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements

The title must be very confusing, but I have to admit, so am I when it comes to regex. My problem is the following:

I have an input string like:

```
{a href=www.google.com}Google{/a} {b}boldText{/b}
```

What I want to achieve is following:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a> <b>boldText</b>
```

I have the following preg_replace function:

```
$input = preg_replace('/\{(\/)?'.$tag.'( [a-z]*\=)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.\:\/]*)?\}/', '<$1'.$tag.' $2"$3">', $input);
```

Where the tag is f.e. `a` or `b` or `script`. The code is working so far, the only problem is that a tag without any attributes comes out like this:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a> <b "">boldText</b>
```

Can I somehow add an `if` condition around the `$2"$3"` in the replacement argument of the `preg_match` function, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: mind to explain the downvote?

Comment: I think you should add why you need to convert only some tags, and not others. I would think of a solution to convert *all* tags to `<...>`

Comment: users can add whitelisted tags in the given syntax, so no html and no quotes are in the database

Comment: Because you are explicitly saying to add a `""`. I'll have a look at the regex

Comment: In your template system, is it possible for a `{b}` tag to have sometimes an attribute or not at all? If not, what are the tags in the same case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd merge the 2 optional groups into 1 and use a 2nd `preg_replace` to add double quotation marks around the attribute values inside opening tags. We cannot do it in 1 go as the replacement pattern is different for tags with attributes.

```
$input = preg_replace('/\{(\/)?'.$tag.'( [a-z]*\=[a-zA-Z0-9\.\:\/]*)?\}/', '<$1' . $tag . '$2>', $input);
```

See [demo on IDEONE](https://ideone.com/2QMAF1)

```
<?php
$tag = "a";
$str = "{a href=www.google.com at=val}Google{/a} {b}boldText{/b}";
$input = preg_replace('#\{(\/)?' . $tag . '\b((?:\s+[a-z]*\=[a-zA-Z0-9\.\:\/]*)*)\}#', '<$1' . $tag . '$2>', $str);
$result = preg_replace("#(?:(<".$tag.")\b|(?<!^)\G)(\s*[^\s=>]+?)=([^=>\s]*)(?=.*?>)#", "$1$2=\"$3\"", $input);
echo $result;
```

Output: `<a href="www.google.com" at="val">Google</a> {b}boldText{/b}`

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace_callback` allows to use a replacement function instead of a string. This gives you the ability to make conditional replacements:

```
$temp = '{a href=www.google.com}Google{/a} {b}boldText{/b}';

$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
{ (?<close>/)? (?<tag>\w+)
(?: # optional attribute part 
    \s+ (?<attribute>\w+) 
    (?: # optional attribute value
        \s* = \s* 
         # works even if it is already quoted:
        (?| " (?<value> [^"]* ) "    # " # <-- these comments are only here
          | ' ([^']*) '              # ' # for the SO highlighter
          | ([^}\s]*)
        ) 
    )?
)?
\s* }
~x
EOD;

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    if ($m['close'])
        return '</' . $m['tag'] . '>';

    if (isset($m['attribute'])) {
        return '<' . $m['tag'] . ' ' . $m['attribute']
             . (isset($m['value']) ? '="' . $m['value'] . '">' : '>');
    }

    return '<' . $m['tag'] . '>';
}, $temp);

echo $result;
```

Advantage: the string is parsed only once because the pattern don't care what kind of tags(*) it is and if it has an attribute or not. The parser is relatively tolerant with the syntax (in particular with whitespaces and eventual quotes).

Inconvenient: the template syntax is not checked. (all tags are replaced including not closed tags or orphan closing tags.)

*(*) You can easily pass an array of allowed tags to the callback function if you want, and why not a multidimensionnal array that contains allowed attributes for each tags.*